# What is the difference between the default disposition for SIGCHLD and explicitly setting the disposition to SIG_IGN?

Tags: linux, signals

*The Linux Programming Interface* says

> **26.3.1 Establishing a Handler for SIGCHLD**
>
> The  SIGCHLD  signal is sent to a parent process whenever one of its
> children termi- nates. **By default**, this signal is ignored, but we
> can catch it by **installing a signal handler**. Within the signal
> handler, we can use wait() (or similar) to reap the zombie child.
> However, there is a subtlety to consider in this approach.
>
> **26.3.3 Ignoring Dead Child Processes**
>
> There is a further possibility for dealing with dead child processes.
> Explicitly setting the disposition of  SIGCHLD  to  SIG_IGN  causes
> any child process that subsequently ter- minates to be immediately
> removed from the system instead of being converted into a zombie. In
> this case, since the status of the child process is simply discarded,
> a subsequent call to wait() (or similar) can’t return any information
> for the termi- nated child.
>
> Note  that  even  though  **the  default  disposition  for  SIGCHLD**
> is  to  be  ignored,
> **explicitly  setting  the  disposition  to  SIG_IGN**  causes  the  different  behavior described here. In this respect, SIGCHLD is
> treated uniquely among signals.

What is the difference between the  default  disposition  for  SIGCHLD and explicitly  setting  the  disposition  to  SIG_IGN?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Explicitly setting the disposition of SIGCHLD to SIG_IGN causes any child process that subsequently terminates to be immediately removed from the system instead of being converted into a zombie.

The default disposition causes child processes to become zombies on exit, until their exit status is retrieved. Setting `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN` indicates that the parent *doesn’t care* about its children’s exit codes, and they are reaped immediately on exit.